# Why did the Kernel unpacking failed?

Tags: 16.04, initrd

The kernel on booting initrd, shows the error 'Initramfs unpacking failed: junk in compressed archive', with a message of kernel panic. Is this an issue with cpio, as I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 or some internal error caused by the /init daemon script?

Comment: Possible related: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe/+bug/1743798

Comment: I tried other formats of archiving, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 1):

I have met similar problems when I am trying to install 4.19-longterm in ubuntu21.10.

The reason is that 4.x kernels don't support `zstd compressing algorithm`, but with which cpio compresses initramfs.

To solve it, edit `/etc/initramfs-tools/update-initramfs.conf` and replace the compressing algorithm to gzip or others supported by your kernel.

run `update-grub` to refresh the rootfs in `/boot/` and reboot.

Comment: Ubuntu 21.10 uses the upstream 5.13 kernel as it's baseline and so takes advantage of a number of improvements since the 5.11 kernel which is used in Ubuntu 21.04. These include the following new features. So ... why are you trying to use a 4.10 kernel?

Comment: I'm working on a research project where the 'CR pinning' security feature is better not supported. Since the mainline merges 'CR pinning' in 5.2, I pick the 4.19 long-term closest in time.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar error on 20.04 on a Thinkpad X220. (Core i5, 8GB RAM, dual-booting with Win10; Ubuntu and Win10 are on separate SSDs.)

20.04 worked for a while and then started failing to boot with errors
about being unable to unpack the initrd and disk errors on the
console.

I found if I went back to an older kernel (via GRUB's Advanced Options
menu) it would boot.

It was scary: I thought my SSD was dying, so I bought a new one.

I copied my partitions onto a new disk with Gparted off a live USB and
put it in a different machine. I booted off a USB key, checked my
partitions for errors with `fsck -f`, and managed to boot into
recovery mode (VERY slowly) and then installed the newer HWE kernel.

This fixed it. It booted fine, without errors except a missing
`resume` device (I used ZRAM and had no swap partition, in order to avoid undue SSD wear).

I have read that newer SSDs are much more robust so I created a swap
partition, put a line for it into `/etc/fstab`. The errors continued.
I had to rebuild my `initrd` which I've never had to do before, but
this fixed it.

So, emboldened, I tried to fix the old laptop. I fsck-ed the
partitions, I ran `trim` on them, I installed the HWE kernel, I
created a swap partition on the other (Windows) SSD and purged ZRAM
and rebuilt my `initrd`.

The machine is still running just fine and now I have a spare SSD I
don't really need, which is a bit annoying. But it only cost me as
much as a takeaway meal, so that is not too bad.